# Can't set allowTransparency when using createElement for iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, createelement

I'm doing `document.createElement` to insert an iframe, but I'm not able to set `allowTransparency`. Here's the code I'm using:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.className = 'example';
iframe.allowTransparency = 'true';
iframe.frameBorder = '0';
iframe.scrolling = 'no';
iframe.style.width = '260px';
iframe.style.height = '120px';
iframe.style.border = 'none';
iframe.src = '//example.com/page';
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

But the output, according to Web Inspector, is just:

```
<iframe class="example" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 260px; height: 120px; border: none; " src="//example.com/page"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
iframe.setAttribute('allowtransparency', 'true');
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this with jQuery? It would be as simple as

```
$(".example").attr("allowTransparency", "true");
```

Your Javascript example seems correct.